# Play Video without touch in AR Vuforia Sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I am working on AR project with Vuforia sdk and following VideoPlayBack sample project, i just want to play video without touch, I mean when marker detect then video will play. I am doing this when marker detect `[videoPlayerHelper[touchedTarget] play:NO fromPosition:VIDEO_PLAYBACK_CURRENT_POSITION];` but it run video greater then marker size. I am getting confuse please help me on that this will be great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an iphone developer I am an android developer,i done that by finding whether marker is being tracking or not,as soon as it start tracking you can start playing video and pause on lost tracking,my ans for this ques for android [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208335/1206201).hope this will clear atleast logic.