# Auto video play in Augmented Reality in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I want to play video automatically when device detects a marker.
How can I achieve this functionality? I'm using Vuforia SDK and VideoPlayBack tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **VideoPlayBack** sample :
If you would like the video to start playing as soon as it starts tracking and pause as soon as tracking is lost you can do that by ***commenting the for-loop*** in VideoPlaybackRenderer.java in method onDrawFrame and instead checking whether the ***isTracking()*** value has changed since the last frame. 
.
**Notice** that you need to be careful not to trigger automatic playback for fullscreen since that will be inconvenient for your users.

Comment: yes i`ve already done it thanx 4 the post

Answer (score 3):

Yes i`ve done it already and its working perfectly fine  and change the things according  to my scenario

Comment: Rather than giving answer that you implemented this functionality, can you better explain how did you make this work?